# Add Identity Provider at a Azure Containter App by CLI or bicep

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-bicep

By a bicep script I created a Containter App which has now one Authentication Identity Provider.
I created also a second App regeistration whcih I want to add to this Container App
This can be done in the Azure Portal, but I want to do this in a script (PowerShell/Bicep)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that this is working:

```
resource containerAppConfig 'Microsoft.App/containerApps/authConfigs@2022-06-01-preview' = {
      name: 'current'  
      parent: containerApp
      properties: {
        identityProviders: {
          azureActiveDirectory:{
            enabled: true
            isAutoProvisioned: true 
            registration: {
              clientId: adApiAppClientId
              clientSecretSettingName: 'api-registry-password'
            }
            validation: {
              allowedAudiences: [
                'api://${adApiAppClientId}'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```